# When does JVM process exit

Tags: java, swing, jvm, event-dispatch-thread

I have the following the situation:

- Started the GUI from the main method (Created a `JFrame` instance).
- From the GUI, I scheduled an event using the class `ScheduledExecutorService`

  `executorService.schedule(this, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`

When the GUI will exit (Event dispatching thread exits), will the JVM also terminate or will it continue to run, with the scheduled thread still ready to dispatch the events?

Comment: That depends on whether the code uses daemon `Thread` objects with the `ScheduledExecutorService`.  If they are daemon, the entire app. will exit once the EDT is shut down.

Comment: JVM exits when the last non-demon thread terminates.

Comment: As far as i am aware the ScheduledExecutorService uses non daemon threads. So the JVM wil stay on even if the EDT ends?

Comment: If that's the case you should add a listener to the frame which shuts down the ExecutorService when the window is closed.

Comment: agree with keuleJ - you should shut down the executor at exit. But you can also System.exit() at the end of your WindowClosing() method and force all the threads to stop if you *need* the JVM to exit when your window closes. Not pretty, but sometimes third-party libraries do wonky things and leave threads running..